# Using Bootstrap with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

Both Bootstrap (v2) and jQuery Mobile (v1.1 RC1) provides building blocks that I want to use for my application.

Bootstrap is clean, simple and wonderful. However, it lacks jQuery Mobile's extremly simple & customizable "List View" which I need to create mobile web applications.

From my simple test, they get in each other's way (messing up some layouts, paddings, sizes, etc).

So, my questions:

1. Can we use both Bootstrap and jQuery Mobile on the same HTML page?
2. If we can't combine them, what is Bootstrap's answer to jQuery Mobile's "List Views"?

Comment: Can we get an update?  What did you end up using (or did you find a way to use both)?  In my simple tests I've also run into conflicts when I used both of them.

Comment: @Jason I ended up picking JQM for mobile and Bootstrap for web. Looks like both UI toolkits serve different needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @kctang did you get an answer for this?? I have the same problem now. trying to use Jquery Mobile ListViews with Bootstrap 2.3 framework and having javascript and css issues. can you please help me in solving this?

Comment: @Sathya IMHO, they don't play well together. If you must have bootstrap l&f, consider the jquery mobile bootstrap theme mentioned below.

Answer (score 7):

### Answer to 1.

What about [jquery-mobile-bootstrap-theme](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme)? ([from author](http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/02/13/New-jQuery-Mobile-theme%3a-Twitter-Bootstrap))

Is a theme for jquery-mobile, it has no bootstrap.

Also, if you want bootstrap, just add bootstrap's css to your webpage, the styles should not collide with jquery mobile, unless you use bootstrap's ids in divs.

You could also override bootstrap's css for small displays to use jquery-mobile. [See this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

```
// Landscape phones and down
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

### Answer to 2.

I think you are looking for bootstrap's 3 [list group linked](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked)