# jQuery / Bootstrap Conflict?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My website has been using the following external files successfully:

```
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

Now I would like to implement a jQuery popup window that requires
the following additional files to work:

```
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
```

But now the text on the page is distorted.  It seems to be stretched
vertically.

Does anyone have a suggestion?  Is there possibly a conflict between
these two jQuery files and the Bootstrap file?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you check browser console for any error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636919/can-i-use-bootstrap-3-together-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: I checked and there was no error.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

A specific jQuery function called `jQuery.noConflict()` can be used to remove conflicts with any other libraries.

you can find more about it here on this [Link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

A small snippet on how to use it -

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea and I will try it.  I might also replace the jQuery.mobile library with another such as jQuery.ui.

Comment: I'll be in touch as soon as I get a chance to try it.  Thanks for offering your help.