# laravel responses become json response when I add jquery mobile library to my view?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, jquery-mobile

It's too wired problem.
for some reason I need jquery mobile library in my project but when I add the following script to my view ,all server responses become json responses and I have no idea about it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
```

NOTE : I just added the script to my project and nothing else has been changed.

I'm using laravel 5.3 and jquery 3.2.1.my front end framework is bootstrap 3.3.7.

any idea guys?

Comment: I would recommend not using jquery mobile alongside bootstrap. For more details as to why check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636919/can-i-use-bootstrap-3-together-with-jquery-mobile

Comment: I would bet jQuery Mobile sets some defaults for `$.ajax`.

Comment: @ceejayoz I guess so but I don't know what to do to prevent jquery to do such thing!

Comment: As advised above, you really shouldn't use jQuery Mobile with Bootstrap. Pick one.

Comment: Try to include jQuery mobile CDN on top of every js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use bootstrap 3 together with jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636919/can-i-use-bootstrap-3-together-with-jquery-mobile)