# Processing events in responsive web page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, responsive-design

I decided to use Bootstrap for development responsive web pages & site. As we all already know these web pages are properly shows on all devices: small devices, modern smartphones, tablets, laptops and desktop computers, and that's nice side of story. But, as far as I know, events handling made by click, hold & press, tap and hold, double tap, double click... on each particular components (button, table row, list box etc) demands different coding approach - for mobile and for regular PC.
Can you please tell me, do I need to mention inside each web page beside mandatory these:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

also this row:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

and if so, where to put it, before jQuery link? Maybe my question could seems silly to most of us but many articles about responsive web sites discuss just about "look" not so much about "feeling", e.g. how to control components on pages.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: events: here You will find the documentation about the JQM virtual events: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmousedown/. for the other question, see here: [Can I use bootstrap 3 together with jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636919/can-i-use-bootstrap-3-together-with-jquery-mobile)

Comment: @deblocker Thanks man, I'll start to read suggested articles. Have a nice day.